# C# how do you create a method that passes an array as an argument?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, arguments

```
private bool DisplayErrorMessages(String array1[], String array2[])
```

Intellisense doesn't show array1 as available and VS2010 has the variable underlined in red

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike in C++, in C# you have to put the square brackets at the end of the Type :

```
private bool DisplayErrorMessages(String[] array1, String[] array2)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
private bool DisplayErrorMessages(String[] array1, String[] array2)
```

Comment: Lol it was so simple Cocoa. How can you not get this?

Answer (score 2):

As Rob showed, you've got your square brackets in the wrong place.

However, you should understand that this isn't just about method parameters - it's *everywhere* you declare an array type variable. For example, local variables:

```
// Valid
String[] x = null;

// Invalid
String x[] = null;
```

It makes more sense this way IMO - it puts all the type information in one place. Why would you *want* to specify it "around" the variable? :)

See chapter 12 of the C# 4 spec for more about arrays in general, including "array types" (12.1).